# If statement running else when the condition should pass

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am struggling finding out why my `if-statement` is failing the condition and running the else statement.

If the answer is 'yes', then an input box should appear under the first question. This isn't the case. If you select no it is showing. You can see in the snippet console that the value in the console is reading correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var radioCheck = '';
 const radios = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="yesno"]'))

 for (const radio of radios) {
  radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
  radioCheck = document.querySelector('[name="yesno"]:checked').value;
  console.log(radioCheck);
   })
 }
 var rsvpAns = $('.radio');
 rsvpAns.click(function() {
  if (radioCheck == 'Yes') {
   $('#ansYes').fadeToggle(400);
  } else {
   $('#ansYes').fadeOut(400);
  }
 });
```

```css
.radio {
 display: none;
}
.radioAnswer {
 width: 220px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 background: #dbc8ca;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 15px 0;
 transition-duration: .4s;
 position: relative;
}
.radioAnswer::before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-style: solid;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 transition: width .4s linear .1s, 
    height .2s linear 1.6s;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 50%;
 transform: rotate(35deg) translateY(-50%);
 transform-origin: center right;
}
input[type=radio]:checked+.radioAnswer {
 background: #0a0;
 color: #fff;
}
input[type=radio]:checked+.radioAnswer::before {
 border-color: #fff;
 transform: rotate(35deg) translateY(-50%);
 height: 1.5em;
 width: .8em;
 transition: all .4s linear 0s, width .4s linear .1s, height .2s linear .3s;
 position: absolute;
}
.radioAnswer {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: .9rem;
 text-align: center;
}
#ansYes {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formField">
  <label class="label">Will you be attending?</label>
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" class="radio" name="yesno" id="yes">
  <label class="radioAnswer" for="yes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" value="No" class="radio" name="yesno" id="no">
  <label class="radioAnswer" for="no">NO</label>
</div>
<div class="formField" id="ansYes">
  <label class="label">How many guests will you be bringing?</label>
  <input type="number" class="input">
</div>
```

Comment: Cause the event trigger order is `click()` then `change()`

Comment: @Hikarunomemory You are correct. Thanks that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just show/hide the `#ansYes` in the change event handler?
Notice I changed `fadeToggle()` with `fadeIn()`.

```js
const radios = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="yesno"]'))

for (const radio of radios) {
  radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
    radioCheck = document.querySelector('[name="yesno"]:checked').value;
    if (radioCheck == 'Yes') {
      $('#ansYes').fadeIn(400);
    } else {
      $('#ansYes').fadeOut(400);
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.radio {
 display: none;
}
.radioAnswer {
 width: 220px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 background: #dbc8ca;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 15px 0;
 transition-duration: .4s;
 position: relative;
}
.radioAnswer::before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-style: solid;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 transition: width .4s linear .1s, 
    height .2s linear 1.6s;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 50%;
 transform: rotate(35deg) translateY(-50%);
 transform-origin: center right;
}
input[type=radio]:checked+.radioAnswer {
 background: #0a0;
 color: #fff;
}
input[type=radio]:checked+.radioAnswer::before {
 border-color: #fff;
 transform: rotate(35deg) translateY(-50%);
 height: 1.5em;
 width: .8em;
 transition: all .4s linear 0s, width .4s linear .1s, height .2s linear .3s;
 position: absolute;
}
.radioAnswer {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: .9rem;
 text-align: center;
}
#ansYes {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formField">
  <label class="label">Will you be attending?</label>
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" class="radio" name="yesno" id="yes">
  <label class="radioAnswer" for="yes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" value="No" class="radio" name="yesno" id="no">
  <label class="radioAnswer" for="no">NO</label>
</div>
<div class="formField" id="ansYes">
  <label class="label">How many guests will you be bringing?</label>
  <input type="number" class="input">
</div>
```